# About live telephone line voltage

Tags: voltage, telephone

I have a question about the telephone line voltage.

When I make a short for 12 volt I see the spark and heating, my question is why I can’t see anything (spark, heating) when I make short with the live telephone line? Although the voltage for the live telephone line is 48 volts.

Comment: Because the current might be limited to less than 30 mA. If it wasn't the [great unwashed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/great_unwashed) would be trying to extract free power from their telecom providers.

Comment: ^^^  exactly that - There's a current-limiter on the pole keeping you from powering your desk lamp or whatever "for free".